# data in datagridview doesnot displayed C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a list of strings as follows:

```
firstname midname lastname
aa        bbb     ccc
bb        lijb    hjhk
```

I want to display in a datagridview. Below is my code:

```
 internal void add_names()
        {
             userInterface ui      = new userInterface();
             List_namez names      = new List_namez();  
             ui.lname.DataSource   = names.getnames().ToList();
             ui.ShowDialog();

        }
```

I am not sure why my list does not displayed when I execute the above code. However when I tried to debug the code I found that ui.lname.DataSource the data is there. But it displays blank rows in datagridview. Any suggestions how to fix this???

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `DataBind()` call after setting the data source.

Comment: In case the columns are not autogenerated you will have to specify the DataProperty Name against the respective columns

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of a name. Let me give you an example:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString( )
    {
        return "Person, name=" + FirstName + " Surname=" + LastName;
    }
}

...

public Form1( )
{
  InitializeComponent( );
  dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler( dataGridView1_RowsAdded );
  dataGridView1.DataSource = new Person[]{ new Person{ FirstName= "Jarek", LastName= "Mitek"},
                                           new Person{ FirstName= "Tony", LastName= "Montana"}};
}

void dataGridView1_RowsAdded( object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "Rows added count: " + e.RowCount + " row index: " +e.RowIndex );
  Console.WriteLine( dataGridView1.Rows[ e.RowIndex ].DataBoundItem.ToString( ) );
}
```

This will generate two columsn, with the name of each column being the property name in the Person class. This is the simplest way to do it.
You will get debug lines showing you when the data is added to the set.
Does that help?